# linkedin api login works perfectly on desktop browsers, android phones but dont work in iPhone devices (iPhone4,5,6)

Tags: ios, iphone, linkedin-api

Desktop and android phone login via linkedin api is working but when i use iphone for this purpose i get userName and password window after that i get white screen nothing else, no redirect also the url is follow of the that white window:

```
 https://platform.linkedin.com/js/xdrpc.html?v=0.0.2000-RC8.49447#state=null&access_token=Q5TZJFBXIHniUQ_MSfp_VDjau118gwTLHFEK&xd_uri=%5B%22localhost%22%5D&member_id=K1LTqvAct1&oauth_cookie_value=%7B%22member_id%22%3A%22K1LTqvAct1%22%2C%22access_token%22%3A%22Q5TZJFBXIHniUQ_MSfp_VDjau118gwTLHFEK%22%2C%22signature_order%22%3A%5B%22access_token%22%2C%22member_id%22%5D%2C%22signature%22%3A%22LpljOpknbyQnPtFts42dOaFFLZE%3D%22%2C%22signature_version%22%3A%221%22%2C%22signature_method%22%3A%22HMAC-SHA1%22%7D
```

Comment: You may wish to edit your question to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).